Showing a media picker with only the media the user gave permission to
I would like to show a media picker to the user with the corresponding media that the user has given permission for.
I show the permission dialog, where the user can select which images/videos they want to grant permission for the app to use. After that, another picker is supposed to appear so the user can choose one media item from this subset, allowing the app to proceed with its intended action.
My problem is that the app is not showing only the media that the user has given permission for; it shows ALL of the media on the device instead.
Here you can see the full process with screenshots.
Here is how I ask for media permission:
 private void requestPermissionsHelper() {
         
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO);
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
     
        requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
      
    }

And its callback, nothing fancy here:
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            boolean valid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                int grantResult = grantResults[i];
                valid = valid && grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            }
           
            if (!valid) {
                DialogHelper.showError(this, "You need to grant acces to media files in order to use this function.");
            }
        }
    }

And this is how I try to show only the media that the user has given permission to, BUT IT SHOWS ALL OF THE MEDIA ON THE DEVICE:
  Intent mediaPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            mediaPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
            mediaPickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            mediaPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
            startActivityForResult(mediaPickerIntent, BROWSE_DEVICE_GALLERY_RC);



And this is how I try to show only the media that the user has given permission to, BUT IT SHOWS ALL OF THE MEDIA ON THE DEVICE:

Well, sure. That is what it is supposed to do. After all, by the user selecting something in the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT screen, they are giving you permission to that content.

another picker is supposed to appear so the user can choose one media item from this subset, allowing the app to proceed with its intended action.

You will have to write this yourself. Your question is phrased as though you are seeking an out-of-the-box, OS-supplied solution for this, and presently there is none.
Your question also does not have any code related to the original media request, so we cannot readily refer to it. Presumably, you have some code that is delivering to you the Uri values of the user's media selections ("the user can select which images/videos they want to grant permission for the app to use"). From there, you would need to:

Design and implement some form of picker UI, using whatever UI framework best fits your app (e.g., LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid() in a Compose UI)

Use those Uri values to obtain suitable images to show in that picker (e.g., Coil leveraging its video frame support)

React to whichever item the user selects from the picker to do whatever comes next

Bypass all of this if the user only selected a single media item originally, as (presumably) you will not need a picker in that case



Here are two parts you need to clarify:


The media permissions granted by the user are only applicable to your app.
The Media Picker is one of the other application or a default feature provided by the OS that support selecting media, meaning it
isn't related your application permission.


So, after the user grants permission to access only some medias on the device, you need implement a library that support media picker.
The example code (e.g e.g https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker)
private void requestPermissionsHelper() {
         
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO);
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
     
        requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (isPermissionGranted) {
            // Show the media picker
            ImagePicker.with(this)
                .crop()                 
                .compress(1024)         
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)  
            .start();
        }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Get your image here
    }
} 

